# TensorFlow with a NER-Tagger

Tags: nlp, tensorflow

I was wondering if there is any possibility to use Named-Entity-Recognition with a self trained model in tensorflow.

There is a word2vec implementation, but I could not find the 'classic' POS or NER tagger.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can adapt the Sequence-to-Sequence model for NER tagging. Your training text is the source vocabulary/sequences to the encoder:

```
Yesterday afternoon , Mike Smith drove to New York .
```

your BIO / BILOU NER tags are your target vocabulary/sequences to the decoder for NER tagging:

```
O O O B_PER I_PER O O B_LOC I_LOC O
```

or instead use POS tags to the decoder for POS tagging:

```
NN NN ,  NNP NNP VBD TO NNP NNP .
```

[IMHO using a deep learning approach usually eliminates the need POS tagging as an intermediate step, unless you specifically need those features as an output for something.]

You would probably want to switch off the word embeddings for the decoder.

This well-known paper applies sequence-to-sequence models to syntactic parsing which has some similarities to the POS and/or NER tasks: [Grammar as a Foreign Language](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7449)

Comment: Hey jmp, thank you for your advice. I adapted the seq2seq model and got it to work. In my encoder I have a lot of digits, lets say "Hello 10.9/12.1 A+". Now when creating the vocabulary file, if have a lot of these numbers in there. This leads to that the model asserts the numbers with a POS-tagging. But my goal is more to learn the "structure" of the data than the actual numbers. You have any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: I think it kind of depends on how your training data is already tokenized and tagged...but you could replace numbers with a special symbol like _NUM when pre-processing your data, for example "Hello _NUM/_NUM A+"

Comment: This is a good idea, I will implement it to see how it works. My raw input data is now "Hello Max 10.9/12.1 A+" which will be preprocessed to Hello Max _NUM/_NUM A+ as encoder input. The decoder input will be "NN NNP NUM/NUM GRA". Thank you for the hint :)

Comment: Your suggestion works well, thanks. If I have lets say two encoder/decoder sequences and I decoded the first, will the second encoding/decoding be influenced by the first one or are they completely independent of each other? Because in the training data, the model learned sentence by sentence.